# ASP.Net : CORS Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cors

Well even though I have enabled CORS in my Controller, yet I get this error.
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

I am trying to post form data to a controller through ajax call.

```
    var data = $.param({
        emailId: $scope.txtEmailAddr,
        passwd: $scope.txtPswd
    });
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    }

$http.post('../api/login/1', data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Success" + data);
            $state.go('app.dashboard.v2');

        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            alert("Error");

        });
```

This is the URL typed on browser:
**http://localhost:27622/template_content_angularjs/index.html#/member/login/v2**
This page has a submit button and on clicking it, it calls the ajax call and internally tries to call the controller api. which gives the above error.

When I call my controller through the browser, it runs successfully and returns data as follows :
Controller url calling through browser: **http://localhost:27622/api/login/1**

The data returned by controller.

```
    <Login xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/kindergarten.template_content_angularjs.Models">
<Password>Adnan@123</Password>
<UserName>Adnan1</UserName>
<id>1</id>
</Login>
```

This is the controller code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using kindergarten.template_content_angularjs.Models;

using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace kindergarten.template_content_angularjs.controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: " http://localhost:27622", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        Login[] ArrLogin = new Login[]
     {
            new Login { id=1, UserName = "Adnan1", Password = "Adnan@123" },
            new Login { id=2, UserName = "Adnan2", Password = "Adnan@123" },
            new Login { id=3, UserName = "Adnan3", Password = "Adnan@123" }
      };

        public IEnumerable<Login> GetAllLogins()
        {
            return ArrLogin;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetLogin(int id)
        {
            var product = ArrLogin.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

I have read through CORS, but still unable to understand, though am calling on the same server, I get the above mentioned error. Also I have enabled CORS in controller.

Comment: The browser uses the GET **method** when loading a url from the address bar but your ajax request makes a POST **method** request. The error msg says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (**Method** Not Allowed)

Comment: What is the solution @Musa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @Musa though said the right thing that ajax request is POST method. The problem was at my controller wherein I was not handling the POST method. 
The solution is

```
public string Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Handling a post method. There was no API at controller for handling the POST method. It was handling the Get Method only.

Sorry folks for the trouble. Hope this helps any other novice like me out there.